# Calling a SQL Server Store Procedure from Excel PowerQuery with datetime parameters is not working for me

Tags: sql-server, excel, powerquery, m

I am new to M.

When trying to call a SQL Server Store Procedure in M, I want to pass parameters to the exec command where SQL is looking for smalldatetime types. I have defined my parameters in PowerQuery as Date/Time, however, when they are added to the exec command I get various errors depending on how I include them.

PowerQuery Parameters

[image]

PowerQuery Code

[image]

Error Returned

[image]

If I change my query to convert the parameters from datetime to text using DateTime.ToText(startDate) I then get the error noting that my stored procedure needs a smalldatetime parameter type as follows, which is of course obvious:

```
DataSource.Error: Microsoft SQL: Error converting data type varchar to smalldatetime.
```

I also want to be able to submit the parameter in 'yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm' format, although if SQL will understand the month and day properly as my users will be in different regions of the world, then I will be happy. If I need to modify my stored procedure to work better with this, I can do that also.

Any help appreciated with thanks.

Comment: The result of `DateTime.ToText(startDate)` isn't in format recognized by SQL Server as valid date time. You need to format it, I will recommend to use `yyyymmdd hh:mm:ss` format. Try to provide the format as second parameter of ToText, like this `DateTime.ToText(startDate, , "yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss")`.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov - That did the trick, I did not include your extra comma from the example - DateTime.ToText(startDate, , "yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss") though, I expect a typo?

Comment: Yes, it's a typo! Sorry about that!